# R - How do I read Shapefiles in from geojson API?

Tags: r

I am used to reading in shapefiles in `Python` with the following simple code:

```
import geopandas

url='https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/01fd6b2d7600446d8af768005992f76a_3.geojson'
gdf = geopandas.read_file(url)
```

I am trying to do it in `R` so that people do not have to download the shapefiles, but I am struggling.

I have tried this, but getting `'cannot open data source'` error:

```
sp <- readOGR(dsn="https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/01fd6b2d7600446d8af768005992f76a_3.geojson", layer="OGRGeoJSON")
```

**If I download the shapefile**, my code looks like this:

```
#load shape file
shape_file_name<- "D:/Users/XXX/Documents/R/NUTS_Level_2_January_2018_Generalised_Clipped_Boundaries_in_the_United_Kingdom.shp"

#import the shape file
shape_file <- readOGR(shape_file_name, stringsAsFactors = F)

#fortify shapefile
shp <- fortify(shape_file)

#creates the NUTS map
NUTS_map <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = shp, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               color = 'lightsteelblue', fill = 'lightcyan', size = .9) +coord_fixed(1.7)+ theme_void()
```

I just want to replace the following lines:

```
shape_file_name<- "D:/Users/XXX/Documents/R/NUTS_Level_2_January_2018_Generalised_Clipped_Boundaries_in_the_United_Kingdom.shp"

shape_file <- readOGR(shape_file_name, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

With a call to the API found at the following webpage:

https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/nuts-level-2-january-2018-names-and-codes-in-the-united-kingdom

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`st_read` from the `sf`-package works fine for me.

```
#load library
library(sf)
#load geojson from url
data <- st_read('https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/01fd6b2d7600446d8af768005992f76a_3.geojson')
#quick view to see what we're dealing with
mapview::mapview(data)
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much, Glad it was a simple fix! I will mark as accepted when I can